# Aptana Studio 3 - How can I change this command (regex replacement)

Tags: css, regex, aptana

*What i want to do:*

edit the CSS command tidier to include a space/tab after the selctor: `#myid{...}` to be `#myid {...}`

*the file I want to edit:*

> format_css_singleline.rb

```
command "Format CSS Single-line" do |cmd|
  cmd.key_binding = "M1+M2+F"
  cmd.output = :replace_selection
  cmd.input = :selection 
  cmd.scope = "source.css"
  cmd.invoke do |context|
    code = $stdin.read
    code.gsub!(/\n{3,}/im, "\n\n")
    code.gsub!(/[ \t]+/im, " ")
    code.gsub!(/(?m)([;:])\s+/im) {|match| "#{$1}" }  //i've tried adding a space after the {$1} here
    code.gsub!(/\s*}/im, "}")
    code.gsub!(/\s*{\s*/im, "{")
    code.gsub!(/[ \t]*,[ \t]*/im, ", ")
    code.gsub!(/@import(.*?);/im) {|match| "@import#{$1};\n\n" }
    code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

*Commands > CSS > Edit this Bundle*. It will grab down a git clone of the original CSS bundle, then generate a project inside the app for you to customize. There you can customize that command's file. Then you'll probably want to edit the following line:
`code.gsub!(/\s*{\s*/im, "{")` to be `code.gsub!(/\s*{\s*/im, " {")`.
That line is collapsing all space before and after `{` down to no space. The modification will leave a space ahead of it.